# Example of Selector grouping and Contextual Selector on CSS

Tags: css

I'm going to have an exam tomorrow and I'm trying to understand the meaning and the answer of

Selector grouping and Contextual Selector

While I searched all around google with many sources it starts to make me confuse because when I answer this on my previous test I got the answer wrong when I used the answer that I found from the internet, but the one below is the correct answer from our professor.

```
a. Selector grouping example 

   td, th, li { property: value; }

b. Contextual Selector example 

   table p { property: value; }
```

Can anyone please give me some more information what does selector grouping and contextual selector mean with some more example please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what you looking at is the following.

for

```
a. Selector grouping example 

   td, th, li { property: value; }
```

what the above is saying that you want to have the same value for the same property for 
all td,th, and li

```
b. Contextual Selector example 

   table p { property: value; }
```

this one is saying that you want to set the value for `<p>` tags that belongs to `<table>` tags

so whenever you have a `<p>` in a `<table>`, then it will get effected.

Answer (score 1):

Selector grouping: Groups the kinds of elements to which style is applied.

Contextual Selector: Check the context of the class in the html tree, assigning the style to the element through a specific route, taking into account the order of depth in the tree.