# I am not sure if I am writing this CSS correctly.

Tags: css

I wrote in parenthesis and in all caps, the things I am confused about in my homework instructions.

This is my homework instructions:

On the first line of your "main.css" file create a comment that reads "general". Under that comment write the following 
Using the universal selector set the margin and padding to zero for all elements. We are doing this to eliminate all the default margin and padding that the browsers add.
Add the css line from the templates page (on the course website) that groups some selectors and sets them all to "display block".
Skip one line and write a comment that reads "wrapper". Under that comment write a css id of "wrapper" and add the following properties.
Give it a width of 1024px
Give it a margin property with the values of 0 and auto (margin: 0 auto centers the page on the browser window. We have to have a width to allow it to show that it is centered.)
Skip one line and write a comment that reads "main".
Put a border of 1px solid #000 around the left, right bottom of the main element.
(NOT SURE IF I DID THIS PORTION CORRECTLY ^)
Add a padding of 10px to the main element. We add a padding so the content will not butt up against the edge of the main element
Using a contextual selector select all the images within the divisional element with the id of "images" and set each image height to 90px, width to 120px and a margin of 20px around the image. We are using CSS to resize our images.
(NOT SURE HOW TO WRITE A CONTEXTUAL SELECTOR TO SELECT ALL THE IMAGES WITH THE DIV ELEMENT WITH THE ID of "images")

This is what I have created but am not sure if it is correct:

```
/* general */
Using the universal selector set the margin and padding to zero for all elements. We are doing this to eliminate all the default margin and padding that the browsers add.

*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

article, aside, figure, footer, header, main, menu, nav, section {display: block;}

<style>
/* wrapper */
#wrapper {width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; }

/* main */
main{border-left: solid 1px #000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000; border-right: solid 1px #000; padding: 10px; }



div images, #images {height: 90px; width: 120px; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The wording in your homework is incredibly poor, but what I **believe** you're looking for is to target all elements with an ID of `images` contained within a DIV. This would be:

```
div #images {
  height: 90px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

This will target any element with the ID of `images` inside any DIV, even if there is an element in between them (such as `<div><span><img id="images"></span></div>`). Note that you can also target **direct descendants** with `>`. `div > #images` will target `<div><img id="images"></div>`, but **not** `<div><span><img id="images"></span></div>`.

Keep in mind that having multiple elements on the page with the same ID is **invalid markup**, and the page will fail to validate correctly. The **only** situation where this would be valid is if your teacher is meaning to have a single element called `#images` on **multiple different pages**. You should use **classes** for targeting multiple elements on the same page. It's possible your teacher meant for you to use a class, which would be `div .images`.

As for your border, you have done it correctly, though note that you can set all four borders at once with the shorthand `border`:

```
main {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that your second line should also be in a comment, or else it will throw a syntax error:

```
/*Using the universal selector set the margin and padding to zero for all elements. We are doing this to eliminate all the default margin and padding that the browsers add.*/
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: For some reason the CSS I have been writing hasn't made any changes to my html pages. I don't see the border that I wrote, and the images sizing hasn't changed. I am writing this CSS in notepad++ and am wondering if maybe I didn't set up my CSS correctly? I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Or maybe I won't see the changes in my html until I upload this CSS document to the server....

Comment: In order to have your changes show up, you will definitely need to both upload the CSS file to the server (or use localhost), and **also** link to the CSS file in the HTML file's `<head>` section: `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"></head>`. Keep in mind that you will need to have the files in the same folder for that example. You may need to adjust the `href` path if they are not in the same folder. You also **may** face a caching issue if you link the files correctly and don't see the changes, which can be fixed by holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon :)

Comment: No problem; glad to hear you worked everything out. If either my answer or the other answer helped you out, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i will try to answer this the best that i can, i am only a programming student so this is my best shot :)

First of all, id's has to be unique you cant have two identical id's on the same page.

If you have etc

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

And you try to style it like #test{background-color: red} only the last div will actually have a red background.

But basically this is what he wants:

```
/*--GENERAL--*/

    *{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    }

/*--WRAPPER--*/
#wrapper{
width: 1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--MAIN--*/
main{
border-left: 1px solid #000;
padding: 10px;
}

div #images img{
height: 90px;
width: 120px;
margin: 20px;
}
```

Examples of [contextual selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239088/example-of-selector-grouping-and-contextual-selector-on-css)

I hope this will help you with your programming journey! :)

Comment: you should use CSS comments `/* CSS comment */`  for CSS not HTML comments `<!-- HTML comment -->`;) ...